# Multiplicação de Matrizes em Fortran

Tags: matriz, fortran

Estou encontrando um problema para compilar um programa em Fortran. O erro de compilação acusa que o *shape* das matrizes não são conformes.  Contudo, eu entendo que é matematicamente permitido multiplicar uma matrix 2x3 por uma matrix2 3x2.

```
mtx1 = | 2 4 1 |      mtx2 = | 3 4 |    Resultado esperado: | 12  18 |
       | 1 3 6 |             | 1 1 |                        | 15  25 |
                             | 2 3 |
```

Esta é a mensagem de erro de compilação:

`print*, mtx1*mtx2 1    2 Error: Shapes for operands at (1) and (2) are not conformable`

---

source code

```
program test
integer :: mtx1(2,3) = reshape((/2,4,1, 1,3,6/),(/2,3/))
integer :: mtx2(3,2) = reshape((/3,4, 1,1, 2,3/),(/3,2/))

print*, mtx1*mtx2

end program teste
```

Comment: Hans, poderia fazer sua pergunta em português?

Comment: Tentei usar a função intrínsice `matmul(mtx1,mtx2)`, compilou, contudo resultado não é consistente.

Comment: Use o botão [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linguagem Fortran usa o modelo *column-major* para armazenar o conteúdo de uma *array* de maneira contígua na memória. Portanto, é necessário ter isto em mente na hora de fazer a atribuição dos valores no construtor de uma variável do tipo *array* (`dimension`); Além disso considerando isso e a resposta de [@Gomieiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/38822/gomiero) (usar a função matmul par amultiplicar matrizes em Fortran), o programa com resultado correto pode ser o do seguinte código fonte:

```fortran
    program test
    
      integer :: mtx1(2,3) = reshape((/2,1, 4,3, 1,6/),(/2,3/)) !column-major
      integer :: mtx2(3,2) = reshape((/3,1,2 ,4,1,3/),(/3,2/))
    
      print ('(" | ",i2,2x,i2," | ")'), matmul(mtx1,mtx2)
    
    end program test
```

Produzindo o resultado desejado:

```
| 12  18 |                                                                                      
| 15  25 |
```

Answer (score 2):

A linguagem Fortran não multiplica matrizes multidimensionais
diretamente, apenas vetores (unidimensionais).

Para multiplicar matrizes multidimensionais, utilize a função
[matmul](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html) (Fortran 90):

```fortran
program test

  integer :: mtx1(2,3) = reshape((/2,4,1, 1,3,6/),(/2,3/))
  integer :: mtx2(3,2) = reshape((/3,4, 1,1, 2,3/),(/3,2/))

  ! -----
  ! Aqui: trocar pela funcao matmul
  ! -----
  print*, matmul(mtx1, mtx2)

end program test
```

Após a execução, o resultado da multiplicação é impresso corretamente:

```fortran
13          22          13          24
```

Comment: eu estava esperando os resultados linha 1 :  12 15 linha 2: 18 25

Comment: Vou tentar uma abordagem na usando a declaração de acordo com column-major no construtor da matriz.

Comment: o resultado `13          22          13          24` não é o que eu esperava como resposta correta da multiplicação das duas matrizes

Comment: A pergunta original era sobre o erro de não-conformidade dos *shapes* da matrizes e não sobre o resultado esperado. Mas após a edição da pergunta e o exemplo que você colocou, sim, está correto, pois os dados precisam estar no formato *column-major*.